# Graph theory for friendship in three cities

Tags: graph-theory

> There are three cities each of which has exactly the same number of citizens, say $n$. Every citizen in each city has exactly a total of $n+1$ friends in the other two cities. Show that there exists three people, one from each city, such that they are friends. We assume that friendship is mutual
>
> ISI B MATH UGB 7/18/2021

I thought of doing this by induction , let $P(k)$ be the statement that the required is true for a city of size $k$

$P(1)$ is trivially true

assume $P(k)$ to be true , then for $P(k+1)$ we can imagine putting one person in each city. Now, when we do this, the previous friendship triplet still exists and hence $P(k+1)$ is true as well.

I discussed this with a friend and he criticized that the question since mathematical, there maybe a possibility that everyone gets amnesia when the new tourists are introduced and hence a new friendship pairs occur and the previous triplet vanishes. I thought it was a fair point, but then I thought, maybe if I could prove that the friendships for three cities of size $n$ is unique, then my proof would hold... but I don't think this is the case.

Can I salvage the proof somehow? If not, how would I do it correctly?

Comment: My blind suggestion, which may not help, is to let $n = 4$, name the people in City-1 1,2,3,4.  Then, name the people in City-2 11,12,13,14.  Then, name the people in City-3 21,22,23,24.  Then, manually explore what happens, trying to prevent the assertion from coming true.  Look for a pattern that forces the assertion to be true.  Try to prove that therefore, the pattern will always assert itself.

Comment: Your induction doesn't work. I would suggest the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Tried that didn't get far @user2661923

Comment: Thought of that, couldn't figure out how to pull it off

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given a person $p$ let $f(p)$ be the minimum of the number of friends that $p$ has on each of the other two cities. Select $p$ such that $f(p)$ is minimized and let $k=f(p)$ and without loss of generality $p$ is in city $1$ and has $k$ friends in city $2$. We deduce $p$ has exactly $n+1−k$ friends in city $3$.

Pick a friend $q$ of $p$ in city $2$. Notice that $q$ has at least $k$ friends in city $3$ and since $p$ has exactly $n+1-k$ friends in city $3$ there must be a friend in city $3$ that is common to $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll recheck it in the morning. I am not understanding from a quick read right now.

Comment: If $p$ has $a$ friends in one of the cities and $b$ in the other one then $f(p)$ is $\min(a,b)$.

Comment: +1 : I know that I am supposed to silently upvote, but, this is really elegant.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it :)

Comment: Minor criticism, if I am understanding the analysis correctly: "$p$  has at least $n+1−k$ friends in city 3" : shouldn't this be $p$ has **exactly** $n+1-k$ friends in city 3?

Comment: Oh yeah, although it seems we can relax the exactness condition, but I'll change it.